# How to check the proceedings of a flagged post?

Tags: discussion, flags

I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890142/why-is-stackoverflow-maintaining-an-active-connection) for moderator attention, which was my own question, and was subsequently closed as being off-topic.

Reason: This question was related to networking, and was asked on stackoverflow which in some gentlemans' words need to be asked on superuser. Okay! I understand that.No Problem.

But then again, people started downvoting it, even one of the answer which was correct in technical terms, started to face downvotes, So I flagged the post for moderator attention as that seems to be the most logical thing to do.

How and where to check the proceedings of that flagged post, as to what moderator has done or planning to do?

EDIT: I just now realized that, because of this same question I got a ban on asking any other question on SO. My question is fully compliant with every law of SO, I searched, researched,gave my attempt and then posted a question, and it was only a few of the questions that I ask. Yes! I am a little frustrated with this. Please mods, do something. What should I do to improve quality of those naive question which I asked when I just joined SO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see your flagging summary at https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1839624. To get to that page, visit your profile on the respective site then click on the number of helpful flags.

Comment: There's a small loophole in the way the profile works - if you don't have any helpful flags yet, then there is no link to click.

Comment: Same here! I couldn't find that tab as well...

Comment: I got that helpful flags tab,i believe it appears after a flag is considered helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Sid At the end of the flag there will be a status, active, helpful, disputed and declined. Helpful means exactly that. Your flag was helpful in the moderation of the site and more than likely some action was taken. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thanks but I am penalized through a ban from asking questions now (which I hardly do). Its an unfair world!

Comment: @Sid Not sure if you've read it yet, but http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th will be the place to understand the question ban. The ban is reversible with a little work!

Comment: I did went through it...and every other question which talks about ban, banning, and unbanning but needless to say, when the penalty is for something I haven't done,or being naive is a crime..I can't buy it. I appreciate your help!