# How can I see my active flags with no prior helpful flags?

Tags: support, flags, profile-page

If I am new to a site and I raise a flag I can't tell how many I have raised or if I have an active flag.

Without any helpful flags on a site there is no link to that page to inform me of the statistics of my flagging habits.

[image: Profile No Flag Link]

How do I find this information without the link there?

Comment: Thats what you get when you make such a broad post. The other half is a dupe too, of [How to check the proceedings of a flagged post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199398) (linked from the feature request I am duping you to).

Comment: that says to click the flag link that isn't present on my profile page @MartijnPieters

Comment: [Here you go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/200242) (no worry, it's giving 404 for anyone except you and diamonds :))

Comment: @Malachi: You need to put your user id in that link...

Comment: Since this is a pure support question asking *how* to see this data and not a feature request asking to add a link, I'm reopening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They've actually changed how this works.

If you have some "impact" on the site (questions or answers) but zero flags at all or if you have zero handled flags or zero validated flags (all declined/disputed), you will see a link to the flag summary page, so while you can enter it manually, you don't need to any longer.

[image: Gaming profile has link to flag history]

If you don't have any impact on the site, however, you will see an explanation of impact and you will still need the link. **This is true even if you do have flags that were declined.** Subsequent attempts to flag after having a flag declined will cause a popup with a link to the page directly, so that's helpful.

[image: Without impact on the site (questions or answers), no link appears and the box reads "Measure your impact Your posts and helpful actions here help hundreds or thousands of people searching for help.]

As few as one "Helpful" flag on a site with zero impact, however, will cause the link to appear.

[image: Has link with helpful flag zero site impact]

Which means that in *most* cases, you should be able to see this link.

---

This was actually addressed in a feature request which is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). [If I have flagged a post, show me a "flags" link in my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199414/if-i-have-flagged-a-post-show-me-a-flags-link-in-my-profile)

Comment: Thank you for following up on this.

Answer (score 16):

Change the profile link from this:

```
https://{Site}.stackexchange.com/users/{your Site UserID}
```

to this:

```
https://{Site}.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/{your Site UserID}
```

and punch it into your Navigation bar.

Comment: Yup. Manually constructing the URL.