# "0 posts edited" is greyed out whereas "0 helpful flags" is clickable. What's the rationale behind that?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

On my user profile, I see that `0 posts edited` is greyed out whereas `0 helpful flags` is clickable. What's the rationale behind that?

[image]

---

> Is there a declined flag perhaps? – [Tinkeringbell**♦**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/369802/tinkeringbell) [54 secs ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359079/0-posts-edited-is-greyed-out-whereas-0-helpful-flags-is-clickable-whats-th#comment1198733_359079)

No declined flag:

[image]

Comment: Is there an unhandled/declined flag perhaps? I'm thinking https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304124/369802 may apply.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Good point, no

Comment: The mechanism and UX are different. "Posts Edited" are additional "Strunk & White" and "Copy Editor" tallies (instead of just a progress bar), while "helpful flags" is a misnomer (it's ***every*** flag, of every description; were one redacted it would be that one too, though a regular user wouldn't see it) - See the profile tabs for ["All Actions" -> "Revisions" underlaid with the Badge Chooser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPymo.jpg). --- Additional Note: One edited post was deleted *after* I got my S&W Badge, but it doesn't assist my "Copy Editor" Badge progress. - I've edited >> than 79 posts.

Answer (score 2):

Probably for seeing your declined/disputed/pending flags. Declined/disputed/pending flags are obviously not counted as "helpful" but users will still want to check the status of their flags.

It would be a waste of developers time to run checks to see if there are any flags and grey the helpful flags button out in accordance with that.

However, this is not the case for posts as you wouldn't need to check your edited posts if you have 0 edits and edit suggestions can be viewed elsewhere.

Hence, there is the difference.

Comment: This is correct. For context and history: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199414/if-i-have-flagged-a-post-show-me-a-flags-link-in-my-profile