# Viewing my flag statuses

Tags: support

I used to be able to view the status of my flags (i.e., whether they were helpful or not helpful) in my profile.  I've been rooting around in my profile quite a bit over the last few days trying to find the status of my most recent flag, and I can't find it.

Is this functionality just gone??

Comment: Can you not see them here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/274872

Comment: Go to your profile (activity tab), and click on the 'helpful flags' under 'impact': https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcBBe.png .. is that what you're looking for?

Comment: If you don't have a helpful flag yet on a particular site, this may be relevant as well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304124

Comment: @Tinkeringbell -- that's the page I used to be able to find on my profile page before things started changing (electrical engineering, if that makes a difference) -- but I can't find it *at all* now, despite looking for some days.

Comment: @Spevacus -- no.  I can't find that page at all.

Comment: How about [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/11684/](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/11684/)?

Comment: Weird. For electrical engineering, your page should be at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/11684/ ... And to me (while not clickable as I'm not a mod there), your activity page does have the impact section with a '310 helpful flags' mention that *should* be clickable for you.

Comment: @Joachim -- that last one works fine, and answers my immediate question of if my last flag was helpful (thanks!) -- but doesn't help users find the info from their profile page -- which seems like where it needs to be.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell -- I can see that EE page (now that I know the (undocumented to users) URL), but I guess I'm wondering whether I should see this info from my profile (like I used to be able to) and why it disappeared from there.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you see on your electrical engineering profile to your question? As far as I know, you should be able to click on your helpful flags and get to that page... Like there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwZrT.png

Comment: Aahh -- I stand corrected.  It does appear on my Activity page.  I was dorking around on the Profile tag.

Comment: Good! If this is closed as a dupe someone should update the answers to the target with recent pictures. If not, someone should turn the comments into an answer here, I gotta run so I'm not doing either :P